# Find the mistake in my solution for the derivative of $x^x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We can easily find the correct derivative of $x^x$ with logarithmic differentiation as follows.

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
y & = & x^{x}\\
\ln(y) & = & x\ln(x)\\
\dfrac{dy}{dx}\dfrac{1}{y} & = & 1*\ln x+x\frac{1}{x}\\
\frac{dy}{dx} & = & x^{x}(\ln x+1)
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

However, I had a friend propose to me the following result:

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
y & = & x^{x}\\
y & = & \underset{x\ times}{\underbrace{x*x*\ ...\ *x}}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

$$By\ the\ product\ rule\ for\ the\ product\ of\ multiple\ functions:$$

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{dy}{dx} & = & \underset{x\ terms}{\underbrace{\underset{x\ terms}{\underbrace{1*x*x*\ ...\ *x}}+\underset{x\ terms}{\underbrace{x*1*x*\ ...\ *x}}+...+\underset{x\ terms}{\underbrace{x*x*\ ...\ *x*1}}}}\\
\frac{dy}{dx} & = & \underset{x\ times}{\underbrace{x^{x-1}+x^{x-1}+\ ...\ +x^{x-1}}}\\
\frac{dy}{dx} & = & x*x^{x-1}\\
\frac{dy}{dx} & = & x^{x}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

The answer is obviously incorrect, but I'm having difficulty finding the flaw in his reasoning. Would anyone happen to see the mistake?

Comment: Because $x$ $times$ is a variable, not a constant - it is the same reason you cant use the power rule to find the derivative of $x^x$ -> $x*x^{x-1}$ -> $x^x$

Comment: Just to clarify, @user130512: It's invalid because the product rule is used with an indefinite number of functions, x, and x isn't necessarily integral in this case?

Comment: What does the original construction using positive integers mean if $ \ x = \frac{7}{2} \ $ ?  If $ \ x = \sqrt{5} \ $ ?  (Or $ \ \pi \ $ for that matter...)  [In fact, in math courses prior to real analysis, we really ask students to take it on faith that $ \ a^x \ , $ much less $ \ x^x \ $ , for $ \ x > 0 \ , $ are well-behaved continuous functions.]

Comment: I understand. That makes perfect sense, thank you.